# How to Collect data for heatmapjs (Incorrect click points are shown)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

For SharePoint Online, I'm trying to collect and store data for mouse click using event.pageX and event.pageY.

Event listener is added to only s4-workspace div element.

But when I try to render using heatmapjs click points are always certain distance pushed from top or incorrect click points.

Could someone suggest JS code on how to collect mouse click x and y coordinates data for certain div in a page.